# Docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF

Tags: docker

When I try to execute the command (run any container)

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling docker properly `curl https://get.docker.com | sh`